# In regex, match instances of a number but only if not accompanied by any other number

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

It was terribly hard for me to make a fitting title for this question. It is much more easily explained by example:

```pcre
test test test 2014 test test // 2014 (truthy)
2014testtest test2014testtest // [2014, 2014] (truthy)
test20141234testtest 2014test // => nothing (falsey)
test 1234 test 2014 test 2014 // => nothing (falsey)
```

So I want to know if the number `2014` is in the string, not accompanied by another other number except other instances of `2014`. Spaces need to be accounted for. As far as whether or not I get an array of matches back, I don't really care. This is truthy/falsey situation.

I'm working with PCRE syntax. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you want to match the whole line?

Comment: Do you want to just match 2014, or is this "any one sequence of digits, but only one such sequence per line"? That is, do you want "test 2015 test 2015" to be truthy or falsy?

Comment: @JonKiparsky sorry I didn't make that clear, "test 2015 test 2015" should be falsy. Looking for specifically 2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `2014` is the only sequence of valid digits that may occur anywhere in the string (but at least once), then the regex is rather simple:

```
^(?:\D*2014)+\D*$
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/pZ0fU0/1).

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of the string
(?:    # Start a non-capturing group that matches...
 \D*   # any number of characters except digits
 2014  # followed by "2014".
)+     # Do this any number of times (but at least once).
\D*    # After that, match any remaining non-digits...
$      # until the end of the string.
```

Comment: this is perfect except it doesn't seem to match a single instance of 2014 when not preceded by a space (presumably). I've been using debuggex (and maybe I shouldn't be), see the unit tests here: https://www.debuggex.com/r/KLmx7klpG3zzWYMt/0

Comment: The regex does assume that 2014 appears on its own. It doesn't have to be surrounded by spaces but it can't be part of an alphanumeric word like `test2014`. This is mainly to exclude numbers like `20145` or `12014`).

Comment: For my purposes this is not bad, but it'd be ideal if it could match 2014 regardless of placement or surrounding characters. Couldn't we utilize `\d` and `\D` to match/exclude digits and non-digits?

Comment: I'm not on my PC anymore where I could quickly test this but `^(?:\D*2014)+\D*$` should work for this.

Comment: All tests passing! https://www.debuggex.com/r/KLmx7klpG3zzWYMt/1 That seems to do it. I will allow you edit your response and I'll +1 and chose as answer. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done by regular expressions in one step.
It sure can't be done by a finite automaton, but "regular expressions" as implemented by most languages have capabilities beyond that.

Try this:

substitute all consecutive non-digits by ';'

extract the first sequence of digits and substitute it in the entire string by a dummy ("a")

check if there are any digits left

Answer (score 0):

You can use [capturing-group](/questions/tagged/capturing-group)s and [backreference](/questions/tagged/backreference)s:

```
^\D*+\b(\d+)\b\D*(\b\1\b\D*)*+$
```

Here digit segments are asserted on word boundaries and a backreference ensures the entire string replicates the same digit segments.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gU1sY1/1), however as the test cases are multiline `[^\d\n]` is used instead. For your actual use case, this is not necessary.